# Facebook Share Image not showing up og:image

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Here is the url im trying to share.

http://goo.gl/0RBj2l

For some reason when i past the original url (not the shortened one) into Facebook  as a post it does not show the listen to this sermon button that i have set as the og:image  WHY??!!

Answer (score 0):

property="og:image"http://pastorsdesk.pryorbaptist.com/gen/listen_to_this_sermon.jpg"

change to

property="og:image" content="http://pastorsdesk.pryorbaptist.com/gen/listen_to_this_sermon.jpg"

your metta tag is improperly formed (missing the content attribute title).